# Django rest API make sure email is verified before giving API token

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm making a Django REST framework for a JSON API, and I want to authenticate Users with a token (so, API request will be something like `.../api/dosomething/{user} Token: ...`).

Django REST documentation [shows](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) how to expose an endpoint for token generation with username/password - however, I'd like to make sure that the email is verified before giving out the token. I don't want to send the token itself to the email, email verification should either be a link or a 6-digit code.

Is there a default way of doing this in Django?

I was thinking of doing the following - on registering at `api/register`, user provides username/email and password, account gets created (but no token so they can't use the API). To get the token, a user needs to hit `api/generate_token` endpoint with username and password. This will generate a random 6-digit code in the backend, store/update the user/code/created_at in the custom model, send an email with the code, and return a message "please verify your email with 6 digit code".

There will be an endpoint `api/verify_email_token` which takes username and verification code. If user/code pair is in the DB and created in the last 30min, it'll create and return a token. Otherwise, it'll fail.

Is this a sound design, and is it already implemented in Django so that I don't need to write the 6-digit code stuff myself? Can I also reuse the same model for password recovery (i.e. `api/reset_password` and `api/verify_email_password` using the same 6 digit code model table)?

Comment: In your custom user model, yo should override the field `is_active`. This field change to  `True` when the user activate its account. Regarding the 6 chars code, I really don't know if it exists something to handle that logic (likely it does, but you have make a deep search). I only have used the package [djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) that permit send emails with a link to activate the accounts. Finally, I don't understand the last question, what do `api/verify_email_password` url? And in what way this is related with `api/reset_password`?

Comment: @Jony_23 OK, using a boolean to check if the user is verified makes sense, thanks. The last question is just a question about implementing password change and requiring the 6-digit email verification code. User would send `.../api/reset_password` request, with just email. Server would send 6-digit code to email. User now needs to submit his username, new password, and 6-digit code to the server, at `api/verify_email_password` endpoint (actually, that's a terrible name, maybe just `api/change_password`).

Comment: I agree to change the name of that endpoint. Now, that logic of 6-digit code to reset/change password could work as long as after using the code, it restarts with a new one and limit to three the attempts. So, you have to program all that in case there's no a package that provide all these functionalities. Other possibility it's send a temporary url where the user be able to reset/change its password (check `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT` IN [Django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/).